# "Exceeds Block gas Limit" Error After Merge

Tags: the-merge

We are running a local eth node and after merge our ledger stopped and we set up a new node but it gives 2 main errors, first "Exceeds Block gas Limit" How we will solve that problem? What should we do to update our services after merge?

Comment: Are you running a Consensus Layer client alongside your Execution Layer node?

Comment: Yes, here the error ; Served eth_sendRawTransaction            conn=12.0.4.67:39190 reqid=552033 duration="279.682µs" err="exceeds block gas limit"